# google-spreadsheet: IMPORTXML не видит сайт

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Мне нужно вытащить цену определенного товара с сайта мобильных запчастей.
Пробовал использовать для этого IMPORTXML

> =IMPORTXML("https://digishop.pro/displey-iphone-7-plus-v-sbore-belyy-pisen/";"//div[@class='c-product-add-to-cart__prices']")
> Но получаю ошибку N/A и объяснение, что ссылка недействительна. Хотя я захожу на неё без всяких проблем. Пробовал на странице повыше, где таблица со всеми дисплеями, использовать IMPORTHTML с аргументом TABLE и всё равно ссылка недействительна.

Answer (score 0):

Это правда - результат работы IMPORTXML функции **зависит от специфики того сайта**, с какого делается попытка импорта.

Если пойти в обход и попытаться загрузить ту же страницу скриптом:

```
function importFrom(url) {
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();
}
```

то в полученном тексте ответа сервера можно заметить важные подробности. А именно - то, что данный сайт защищен от DDoS атак средствами [CLOUDFLARE](https://www.cloudflare.com/), а проще говоря - скриптами, которые должны быть выполнены в браузере на стороне клиента - до того, как браузер получит настоящее содержимое страницы с товарами и ценами. В этот момент код ответа сервера равен 503 вместо "полноценного" 200. Обычный браузер проходит эту стадию автоматически, быстро и прозрачно для пользователя, отправляя следующий запрос на сервер и получая от него полный ответ. Однако в случае с функцией IMPORTXML никакой работы с клиент-сайд скриптами вообще не предусмотрено. Ответ сервера с кодом 503 функция IMPORTXML интерпретирует как невозможность получить информацию с данного ресурса, что мы и видим в ячейке таблиц.

То же самое происходит и при использовании IMPORTHTML.